# Iphone map direction

Tags: ios, iphone, redirect, dictionary, mapkit

Does anybody know if I can show the direction between two points using UIMapKit or another component (if there is any) just like how it is shown on the map used by Iphone with the same features (walking , driving )?

Answer (score 0):

There's no public API for that. You might wanna check out [CloudMade](http://cloudmade.com/products/iphone-sdk)'s or [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)'s services.

**Update: This is possible as of iOS 6 or later. Check the documentation for MKDirectionsRequest.**